# Counting Paragraph and Most Frequent Words in Python Text File

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, for-loop, count

I am trying to count the number of paragraphs and the most frequent words in a text file (any text file for that matter) but seem to have zero output when I run my code, no errors either. Any tips on where I'm going wrong?

```
filename = input("enter file name: ")
inf = open(filename, 'r')
#frequent words 
wordcount={}
for word in inf.read().split():
 if word not in wordcount:
    wordcount[word] = 1
else:
    wordcount[word] += 1
for key in wordcount.keys():
    print ("%s %s " %(key , wordcount[key]))

#Count Paragraph(s)
linecount = 0
for i in inf:
   paragraphcount = 0
   if '\n' in i:
      linecount += 1
   if len(i) < 2: paragraphcount *= 0
   elif len(i) > 2: paragraphcount = paragraphcount + 1
   print('%-4d %4d %s' % (paragraphcount, linecount, i))  
inf.close()
```

Comment: Rather than closing the file, consider opening the file in a context manager using a `with` statement.  Also confirm the [file mode](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm) you wish to use, i.e. `r+`.   Loop over lines in the file using `enumerate(inf.readlines)`; you can then split words and count lines for each line.  Finally, use `collections.Counter` for counting words and paragraphs rather than classic incrementers.  These suggestions can make your code more pythonic.

Answer (score 2):

```
filename = raw_input("enter file name: ")

wordcount={}
paragraphcount = 0
linecount = 0
with open(filename, 'r') as ftext:

    for line in ftext.readlines():
        if line in ('\n', '\r\n'):
            if linecount == 0:
                paragraphcount = paragraphcount + 1
            linecount = linecount + 1
        else:
            linecount = 0
            #frequent words
            for word in line.split():
                wordcount[word] = wordcount.get(word,0) + 1




print wordcount
print paragraphcount
```

Comment: Rather than a regular `wordcount` dict, you could use a `defaultfdict`, e.g. `wordcount = collections.defaultdict(int)` --> `wordcount[word] += 1`.

Answer (score 1):

When you are reading a file, there is a cursor that indicates which byte you are reading at the moment. In your code, you are trying to read the file twice and encountered a strange behavior, which shoud have been a hint that you are doing something wrong. To the solution,

### What is the correct way ?

You should read the file once, store every line, then find word count and paragraph count, using the same store. Rather than trying to reading it twice.

### What is happening is the current code ?

When you first read the file, your byte cursor is set to the end of the file, when you try to read lines, if returns an empty list because it tries to read the end of the file. You can corrent this by resetting the file pointer(the cursor).

Call `inf.seek(0)` just before you try to read lines. But instead of this, you should be focusing on implementing a method I mentioned in the first section.